React. Можно ли кто улучшить код?
Здраствуйте! Хотел бы попросить вас помлщь с этим кодом.
import {
  useState
} from 'react';

import styles from './style/Component.module.css';
export function Dropdown() {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false)
  
  function toggle() {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen)
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      <button className{styles.main} onClick={toggle}>On</button>
      {
        isOpen && (
          <div className={styles.dropdown}>
            <ul>
              <li>1 list</li>
              <li>2 list</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        )
      }
    </div>
  )
}

Нужно ли его улучшать и если да, то как? Посоветуйте.

Да чего тут улучшать? Тут три строчки кода. Если бы тут было несколько компонентов взаимосвязанных, да ещё с логикой (обычной или бизнес) и какая-нибудь каша - то да, можно было бы о чём то говорить. А так.....ну код и код.....обычный....... Это всё равно что оценивать код let myVar = 'hello world!'; console.log(myVar);

Согласен с Алексеем. А так, по мелочи: все <li> вынести в рендер через map. Заменить setIsOpen(!isOpen) на setIsOpen(o => !o) для работы с предыдущим состоянием. Но это так. наведение порядка на чистом столе... З.Ы. и для крастоы меняем >On< на >{ isOpen ? 'Off' : 'On' }<


Я бы изменил название функции-обработчика. Например, handleToggle.
Так сразу понятно, что это обработчик события.

Еще, для функций-обработчиков стараюсь применять стрелочные функции.
В классовых компонентах это поможет избежать проблем с потерей
контекста this.

Вот так лучше не изменять состояние setIsOpen(!isOpen).  Могут
быть ситуации устаревания переданного в обработчик состояния isOpen.
А еще, тут у тебя следующее состояние явно зависит от предыдущего.
Перепиши вот так setIsOpen((currentState) => !currentState).
Так ты даешь React-у инструкцию "Взять текущее состояние и
инвертировать его"



Бро. Опрёделено! Это здорово. Спасибо! Учту эти аспекты.

Ваш код никак невозможно улучшить если учесть то что тут ничего лишнего и кода тоже мало. А, стоп. У вас ошибка в коде. Вот исправный код: <button className{styles.main} onClick={toggle}>On</button>. И еще <ul> {list.map((v,i) => (<li key={i}>{v} list</li>)} </ul>
